# NLog appsetting default to relative path

Tags: .net, logging, nlog

I want to use [`<appsetting>`](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AppSetting-Layout-Renderer) in [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog) ([the NLog.Extended NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extended/) to be specific) to do something like this:

```
<variable name="logDir" value="${appsetting:name=RemoteLogDir:default=.\Log}" />
```

Where I set up `RemoteLogDir` when I publish my app, but fallback to a *relative* directory for local development. I've been able to get an *absolute* path to work, but that doesn't seem collaborator-friendly.

**How can I get a relative path to work? Or do I need to submit a feature request?**

Notes:

- I'm using NLog 4.4.12 and NLog.Extended 4.0.0.1.
- I'm using .NET 4.6.1 on Windows (10).
- [I've cross posted to the NLog repository](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2307).
- The NLog.config is this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true" throwExceptions="false">

  <variable xsi:type="NLogVariable" name="appLogName" value="MyApp"/>

  <variable xsi:type="NLogVariable" name="logDir" value="${appsetting:name=RemoteLogDir:default=\.\\Log}" />
  <variable xsi:type="NLogVariable" name="layout" value="${level:uppercase=true} | ${date:format=MM/dd/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss} | ${machinename} | ${windows-identity:domain=true} | ${callsite} ${newline}    ${message}${onexception:${newline}[EXCEPTION]${newline}${exception:format=tostring}}" />

  <variable xsi:type="NLogVariable" name="logFileName" value="${var:logDir}/${var:appLogName}_${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.txt" />
  <variable xsi:type="NLogVariable" name="archiveLogFileName" value="${var:logDir}/Archive/${var:appLogName}_Archived_{#}.txt" />

  <targets>
    <target name="singleFile" xsi:type="File"
              layout="${var:layout}"
              fileName="${var:logFileName}"
              concurrentWrites="true"
              keepFileOpen="true"
              archiveFileName="${var:archiveLogFileName}"
              archiveEvery="Day"
              archiveNumbering="Date"
              archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd_HH"
              maxArchiveFiles="30" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="singleFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

```xml
<variable xsi:type="NLogVariable" name="logDir" value="${whenEmpty:whenEmpty=${basedir}/Log:inner=${appsetting:name=RemoteLogDir}}" />
```

**Explanation**

Indeed, the [appsetting](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AppSetting-Layout-Renderer) only accepts a string for the default value. However, you can emulate the desired functionality by supplying no default and using [whenEmpty](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/WhenEmpty-Layout-Renderer). When the app setting isn't set, the inner value will be counted as empty, so the whenEmpty value is rendered.